# Why does chrome.tabs.create create 2 tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When the chrome.tabs.create function is triggered by a message received, it creates 2 tabs. In the following demo code, 1 cat tab is created, and 2 dog tabs are created.

Is this by design or is it a bug? If it is a known bug, can you provide the bug id so I can track its progress? How can I avoid 2 duplicate tabs being created?

The debug console contains the following output, so in fact the duplicate tab is also getting the content script injected even though only one call to secondaryTabCreationCallback_ is printed in the debug output!!!!

```
Creating secondary tab
Created secondary tab: 11968
Kill request from tab: 11966
Kill request from tab: 11968
```

### background.js

```js
var handler = {
  url1_: 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cat',
  url2_: 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=dog',

  windowId_: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,

  createPrimaryTab: function() {
    chrome.tabs.create(
        {'url': handler.url1_, 'active': false, 'windowId': handler.windowId_},
        handler.primaryTabCreationCallback_);
  },

  primaryTabCreationCallback_: function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
  },

  createSecondaryTab_: function() {
    console.log("Creating secondary tab");
    chrome.tabs.create(
        {'url': handler.url2_, 'active': false, 'windowId': handler.windowId_},
        handler.secondaryTabCreationCallback_);
  },

  secondaryTabCreationCallback_: function(tab) {
    console.log("Created secondary tab: " + tab.id);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script2.js"});
  },
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (message.type) {
    case "CREATE_TAB":
      handler.createSecondaryTab_();
      break;
    case "KILL_ME":
      console.log("Kill request from tab: " + sender.tab.id);
      // chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
      break;
    default:
      alert("Not Reached");
      break;
  }
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')});
});

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("start_button").onclick = handler.createPrimaryTab;
}
```

### content_script.js

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "CREATE_TAB"});
```

### content_script2.js

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "KILL_ME"});
```

### background.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="start_button" value="Start">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Tab Bug",
  "description": "Demonstrates bug in chrome.tabs.create.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "tabs",
    "https://www.google.com/"
  ],
  "icons": { "128": "icon128.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon19.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your `"content_scripts"` field in the manifest file?

Comment: The content_scripts field should only be used if the content_scripts should always be injected into every page, not if they should be programmatically injected. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there are 2 "background" pages running.

1. The official background page specified in the manifest file.
2. The tab created by `chrome.tabs.create({'url':
   chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')})`.

This means there are 2 message listeners, which is why 2 tabs are opening.

The console messages from the official manifest.json background can be found by looking at extension on the chrome extensions page and click on the "Inspect views: background.html". Which shows:

```
Creating secondary tab
Created secondary tab: 11966
Kill request from tab: 11966
Kill request from tab: 11968
```

To work around this issue. The manifest.json background file can point to a script "starter.js" instead of an html page, which simply has the following javascript:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My `background.js` is very simple.

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html'),
  })
})
```

##### manifest.json

```yaml
"background": {
  "persistent": false,
  "scripts": [
    "background.js"
  ]
},
```

Tried to disable/enable the extension (so that chrome destroys all the background pages from this extension) but it still opens duplicate tabs!!

So the problem might be there is someone that included the `background.js`. And guess what! It's `popup.html`.

The root cause is `HtmlWebpackPlugin` from `webpack.config.js`. It defaults to include all `chunks` (including `background`).

So we just exclude the `background` chunk from popup.html config then it should work as expected.

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'public/popup.html',
  filename: 'popup.html',
  excludeChunks: ['background'],
}),
```